# Jmeter HTTP Request with file protocol is not taking all the file

Tags: java, file, http, upload, jmeter

I want to simulate a response data with a local .xml file

I found this way, putting "file" in http protocol and the location of the file in "patch", it seems to work just like i need but the .xml file size its 250mb and the response data of the jmeter is cutting the complete file and its only showing me a part of it. I think its not taking all the file because already try to change the "view.results.tree.max_size" but that its not the problem.

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

If there another way i will listen but i need the file like a response data, not like a variable.

Thanks!

PD. Dont look the console errors that appears in the first photo, i just forgot to clean those.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 [JMeter Properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html) which are responsible for the response data storage and visualization:

- `httpsampler.max_bytes_to_store_per_request`
- `view.results.tree.max_size`

Make sure to set them to `0` by adding the next lines to *user.properties* file:

```
httpsampler.max_bytes_to_store_per_request=0
view.results.tree.max_size=0
```

**JMeter restart will be required to pick the properties up**

Check out [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/) for more information on different JMeter properties types and ways of setting/overriding them.

Comment: that didn't work for me, but thanks anyway, i think i would need a alternative way